# How to avoid google play redirect

Tags: android, facebook, applinks

I have added the following tags on my page:
http://www.lth-hlh.com/test/exmaple

```
<meta property="al:android" />
<meta property="al:android:package" content="com.example.venezia" />
<meta property="al:android:url" content="exmaple://apps/android?param=B00FAPF" />
<meta property="al:android:app_name" content="Example App Store" />
```

When com.example.venezia is not installed on the device, FB is prompting to redirect to the google play store. How to avoid this and just load the page's url directly?

Comment: Have you tried adding `al:web:url`?

Comment: Usually, if `al:web:should_fallback` is not set to `false`, then the current page content will be served. Unless you have `al:web:url` which then will be served instead. Have you tried @CBroe suggestion and see if that works for you?